# Can somebody share the whole conversation between Bill Weasley and HP about Goblins?

Tags: harry-potter, money

Can somebody share the whole conversation between Bill Weasley and Harry Potter about Goblins. The conversation happens after Dobby the free Elf is killed; HP buries him with his own hands and goes to Griphook to ask for help where the said conversation takes place.

I was able to get part of that conversation -

> "We are talking about a different breed of being. Dealings between
>   wizards and goblins have been fraught for centuries ... There has been
>   fault on both sides, I would never claim that wizards have been
>   innocent. However, there is a belief among some goblins, and those at
>   Gringotts are perhaps most prone to it, that wizards cannot be trusted
>   in matters of gold and treasure, that they have no respect for goblin
>   ownership."  - Bill Weasley talking to HP about Goblins view of magical things.

**Can someone share the rest of this conversation between Harry and Bill?**. I do have another sub-question though, from the conversation (as I remember) it does seem that Goblins were in the right from their PoV, are there any other examples in any of the newer writings of J.K. Rowling which dwells on this ownership aspect by Goblins ?

-

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60724/who-was-the-rightful-owner-of-the-sword-of-gryffindor

Comment: Also: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117868/why-would-gringotts-need-a-curse-breaker/117872

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote taken from the answer by @DavidS on [Why would Gringotts need a Curse-Breaker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117868/why-would-gringotts-need-a-curse-breaker/117872)

> "We are talking about a different breed of being. Dealings between wizards
> and goblins have been fraught for centuries ... There has been fault on both
> sides, I would never claim that wizards have been innocent.
> However, there is a belief among some goblins, and those at Gringotts
> are perhaps most prone to it, that wizards cannot be trusted in
> matters of gold and treasure, that they have no respect for goblin
> ownership."
>
> "I respect --" Harry began, but Bill shook his head. "You
> don't understand, Harry, nobody could understand unless they have
> lived with goblins. To a goblin, the rightful and true master of any
> object is the maker, not the purchaser. All goblin made objects are,
> in goblin eyes, rightfully theirs."
>
> "But it was bought --"
>
> "-- then
> they would consider it rented by the one who had paid the money. They
> have, however, great difficulty with the idea of goblin-made objects
> passing from wizard to wizard. You saw Griphook's face when the tiara
> passed under his eyes. He disapproves. I believe he thinks, as do the
> fiercest of his kind, that it ought to have been returned to the
> goblins once the original purchaser died. They consider our habit of
> keeping goblin-made objects, passing them from wizard to wizard
> without further payment, little more than theft."

I believe this is the entireity of the dialogue between Harry and Bill on this subject.